# How to set Authorization header using PHP

Tags: php, apache, basic-authentication, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I am using `apache` basic authentication and which sets up `REMOTE_USER` header that I my server verifies for allowing in. I am using `apache` reverse proxy.

```
ProxyPass /location http://myip:8000/location
ProxyPassReverse /en-US http://myip:8000/location

<Location /location>
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Files"
# (Following line optional)
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /home/tomcat/apache/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=RU:%{REMOTE_USER}]
RequestHeader set X-Remote-User %{RU}e
RequestHeader set REMOTE-USER %{REMOTE_USER}s
</Location>
```

Above solution is working fine. But I need to do same with `PHP`. Can I send php redirect to /location with headers similar to above authentication headers.

I need to do user authentication with php and after authentication is done I want to let him in with above `proxypass.`

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the PHP [`header`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function to send the `WWW-Authenticate` and `401` headers:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=<YOUR REALM>");
```

Then, use `$_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"]` and `$_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_PW"]` to get the username and password entered.

To put it all together:

```
<?php
    header("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized");
    header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=<YOUR REALM>");

    if (!($_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"] == $username && $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_PW"] == $pw))
    {
        exit("Sorry, you entered the wrong username and password.");
    }
?>
```

Comment: I want it to redirect to /location using php and should have %{REMOTE_USER} variable value of username. Apache will read %{REMOTE_USER} and will let me in. Thanks.

Comment: @Kalpesh so, if the person gets the right password and username, you want them to be redirected?

Comment: @Kalpesh oh, do you want *Apache* to authenticate the user and then PHP redirect them?

Comment: right now apache is authenticating and redirecting with proxy and headers to target. Instead I was custom authentication with php and redirect with same headers set using php so that target will let me in. Target server needs those header to verify idenity.